# Reflecting Charges in $E$-Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

**Edit**

[image: Sketch]

Imagine a system in which particles are contained in a chamber with a Magnetic field located at the end, which has a thickness of t and a known diameter. For some charge $q$, with known input velocity, how could you define a mathematical system to calculate the ratio of charges held in a constant loop in the B-field to charges "reflected" back out, as seen in the attached sketch? Would it be more likely that the charges simply hit the chamber wall and then reflect back?

I believe representing a distribution of angles and vertical positions and then finding their end state is the best way, but how can that be done, with code maybe?

Thank you for @Trula response to the previous sub-question, regarding how a neutral atom is effectively given a charge $q = 0$.

Comment: the neutral atom is not affected by E. E can polarize an atom. but since it charge q = 0  your F=q*E is 0

Comment: @trula, thankyou, let me edit the question to remove that part from it.

Comment: What do you mean loops and reflecting from an electric field? Also since you aren't talking about neutral atoms anymore you should probably also edit the question to be a bit more descriptive and accurate .

Comment: Charges never loop in any homogenous E field also the reflection you draw is impossible. do you mean a B- field?

Comment: @trula, Is my understanding incorrect then? Can this occur in a B field? Would you mind explaining why this doesn't occur in an E field?

Comment: To add, this is more of a thought experiment, would a B field receive the required reflection?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a B field instead of an E field, because for the "looping' that you are talking about, which is just a circular motion, the force acting on the charge has to be perpendicular to its velocity at all time.

Within an E field, the force acting on a point charge q is given by
$\vec{F} = q\vec{E}$ and acts in the direction of the field for a positive charge and opposite the direction of the field for a negative charge. It is also independent of the velocity, so you will get a parabolic trajectory in a uniform E field towards one of the plates.

Assuming you mean a B field, such circular motion is possible. The force on a moving point charge in a B field is given by $\vec{F} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$. Due to the cross product, the force on the point charge is perpendicular to its velocity at all times and results in a circular motion. That being said, you might realise a problem with your question.

Assume the magnetic field acts perpendicular to the container into the page (since you said diameter of the container, its circular and this extends to any magnetic field which is perpendicular to the container). You might realise that any particle that enters this field is necessarily reflected backwards, looking at the image below

[image: charged particle entering a magnetic field at an angle and exiting tracing a section of a circle]

A negative particle entering this field traced almost a full circle but because it necessarily exits the field by symmetry before it can finish, it is sent back (note that since we are looking at it from the side, any component of the velocity of the particle in the direction of the magnetic field does not matter as it does not result in a force acting on the particle). The true motion of a particle entering a magnetic field at an angle is a helix as shown below

[image: charged particle in a helical trajectory after entering a magnetic field at an angle]

The first image that we saw was the view of the helix head on, which is why it looks like circular motion. If the B field had a component parallel to the container it would mean the helical path moves in the direction of the magnetic field (assuming it does not already exit the field). In this case it will either reach the end of the magnetic field or it will collide into the wall of the container and the helical path reflects, also causing it to reach the end of the field.

In conclusion, if you meant an E field, the particles would just be attracted towards one plate and either reach the plate by parabolic motion or reach the end of the E field due to the field not being long enough. If instead you meant a B field, all particles would either be sent back or pass through. In either case, the ratio of particles being "held" in the field by circular motion is 0.

Comment: Yes, I believe that I did mean B field, thankyou. How would you mathematically determine if it leaves the B field or stays? Is that a problem of geometry?

Comment: Once again thankyou @Cheerful96.  If the initial v and q,m and B are known to be constant at all points (simple model), then the radial path can be determined. Then I guess that can determine what happens from there, but would the velocity entering the field, be the same as in the field, or would it accelerate?

Comment: @Jack, as for the velocity of the particle, it always remains a constant, because the nature of the B field is that the force acts perpendicular to the motion. No component of the force acts in the direction of the velocity so although the particle undergoes acceleration, it is only due to the change in its direction, and not magnitude.

Comment: As for whether it leaves the field, if the angle between the field and the x axis (horizontal) is not 90, a part of the field acts in the direction of the axis. Any particle that is not projected perpendicular to the field will undergo helical motion and hence will reach the end eventually. If the field is instead perpendicular to the container, then you can check using trigonometry if the length of the field (t) is smaller than the diameter of the circular path (which would cause the particle to leave out the other side before it can turn back), and you can find a relationship between v and t

Comment: Finally, as a side note, when you say "How would you mathematically determine if it leaves the B field or stays?", the particle by definition cannot remain inside the field because of the initial conditions (assuming t is not infinite, which would make the whole question redundant)

Comment: so any particle that enters, would always leave from the same initial direction, given the field has a large enough thickness?

Comment: not true, as a particle undergoing helical motion would exit from the OPPOSITE direction, because of its velocity along the direction of the field being unchanged. If it undergoes partial circular motion, then assuming the field is large enough, yes it would exit from the same direction it entered.